# How to fix IP filter regular expressions written using shell script command in Linux?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, filter, ip

It doesn't work in shell script, but in javascript, it works fine, what's wrong with that?

> I just want to filter out all IPs that are not in the range of 2~254, for example, ignore the `255`

### shell script

> I want to filter out the IP `192.168.18.255` only using the `standard regular expressions`.

1. current useful input IPs: `192.168.18.195 192.168.18.255`
2. wanted output IP: `192.168.18.195`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IPs=$(ifconfig | grep -oE '(192\.168\.1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])')
echo $IPs
# 192.168.18.195 192.168.18.255 ❌

IPs1=$(ifconfig | grep -oE '192\.168\.(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])')
echo $IPs1
# 192.168.18.195 192.168.18.25 ❌

IPs2=$(ifconfig | grep -oE '192\.168\.(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$')
echo $IPs2
# ❌

# wanted, ignore 192.168.18.255 ❓
# IPs=$(ifconfig | grep -oE '❓')
# echo $IPs
# 192.168.18.195
```

[image]

**This `minimal reproducible` version input just for testing.**

```bash
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
        ether a4:83:e7:91:62:79 
        inet6 fe80::1ca2:3b0a:df9d:465f%en1 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x7 
        inet 192.168.18.195 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.18.255
        inet6 fd80:eae6:1258:0:37:7544:1d1:7b08 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active
```

```bash
$ ifconfig
# The output is too long, ignore it here, Please see the link below
```

The full version output of `ifconfig` link: https://gist.github.com/xgqfrms/a9e98b17835ddbffab07dde84bd3caa5

### javascript

> This is just used for test ignore the IP `255` works well.

```js
function test(n) {
  let reg = /192\.168\.(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$/;
   for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     let result = reg.test(`192.168.18.${i}`);
     if(result) {
       // console.log(`192.168.18.${i} ✅`, i, result)
     } else {
       console.log(`192.168.18.${i} ❌`, i, result)
     }
   }
}

test(256);

192.168.18.0 ❌ 0 false
192.168.18.1 ❌ 1 false
192.168.18.255 ❌ 255 false
```

[image]

### refs

https://regexper.com/

https://regex101.com/

Comment: What is your current output of `ifconfig` and what is your expected output?

Comment: Your input in bash and js differs. First one is lines containing ip somewhere in it, second - only ip. Try replacing `$` in your third attempt in bash with `[[:space:]]`

Comment: @markalex It's not very clear, please show your full code, It's not valid `IPs2=$(ifconfig | grep -oE '192\.168\.(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])[[:  :]]')`

Comment: Not `[[:  :]]`, literally `[[:space:]]`

Comment: If your `ifconfig` output is too long to include in your question then it's too long for us to read. Please replace all the links and images with plain text that we can copy/paste to test with so we can help you. Keep in mind you're supposed to create and post a [mcve] that concisely demonstrates your problem, not just whatever data you have lying around.

Comment: Because stackoverflow's markdown editor not support `<details><summary></summary></details>`, so ignoring output that is too long will be easier for humans to read. And I had add a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### solutions

| test environment | result |
| --- | --- |
| macOS 13.1 | ✅ |
| Raspberry Pi OS x64 | ✅ |

1. `\b`

> It's very brief and clear. `word boundary`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IPs=$(ifconfig | grep -oE '192\.168\.(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])\b')
echo $IPs
# 192.168.18.195
```

[image]

2. `[[:space:]]`

> This usage is not common, and not easy to understand.

It seems to be called `character class keywords` in GNU Linux.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IPs=$(ifconfig | grep -oE '192\.168\.(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])[[:space:]]')
echo $IPs
# 192.168.18.195
```

[image]

3. `grep -w`

> It only works with `grep`, but is not compatible with standard regular expressions.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IPs=$(ifconfig | grep -woE '192\.168\.(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])')
echo $IPs
# 192.168.18.195
```

[image]

```bash
$ man grep

# ...

     -w, --word-regexp
             The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by
             ‘[[:<:]]’ and ‘[[:>:]]’; see re_format(7)).  This option has no
             effect if -x is also specified.
# ...
```

### refs

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Assertions#:~:text=it%20in%20%22eat%22.-,%5Cb,-Matches%20a%20word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Assertions#:%7E:text=it%20in%20%22eat%22.-,%5Cb,-Matches%20a%20word)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm

Comment: `[[:space:]]` is not specific to Linux or GNU; it is a POSIX standard. The problem with `[[:space:]]` is that it only matches actual whitespace characters, not end of line; so it will find a word boundary only where that is a literal whitespace character, but not adjacent to beginning or end of line. It's hardly harder to understand than `\b`, but obviously means something else. (Some regex variants support `\s` instead of `[[:space:]]` but again, that's not portable or robust.)

Comment: The problem with `\b` is that it is less portable. I will repeat my suggestion to prefer `-w` instead.

Comment: While `grep -w` works, it's not what I want.

Comment: Why not? Why do you say it's "not compatible with standard regular expressions"? Are you trying to say you want to express the boundary condition within the regex itself?

Comment: You could use `(^|[^[:alnum:]_])` for a beginning word boundary and `([^[:alnum:]_]|$)` for an ending word boundary, but my experience is that some regex implementations don't properly support this either.

Comment: I mean in the standard regex world, there is no `-w`.

Comment: `\b` exists in most programming languages, such as, shell, javascript, python, java and so on. This's what I said common.

Comment: But `[[:space:]]` only exists in the `POSIX` world, so it's not very common, as far as I'm concerned. I've never seen `[[:space:]]` before.

Comment: That's balderdash; because it's in POSIX, it's supported on every even vaguely modern platform. Not having seen the POSIX classes in actual use doesn't mean they're not there.

Answer (score 1):

Since output of your `ifconfig` contains not of only IPs, but also of text surrounding it, `$` is not the only valid marker of IP end.

Simplest way would be to replace it with `\b`: word boundary. But it will work only if you are using GNU `grep`.

If your grep lacks support of `\b` you can use `([[:space:]]|$)` or `[^0-9]` instead. It will capture symbol following the IP if it is (whitespace or end-of-line) or non-digit correspondingly.

Example of command with output of your `ifconfig` stored in file `input_file.txt`:

```bash
$ ifconfig > input_file.txt

$ cat input_file.txt | grep -oE '192\.168\.(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])([[:space:]]|$)'
192.168.18.195
```

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LY2pjB/1).

Comment: Probably avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat). A simpler fix is to use `grep -w` to avoid having matches cross word boundaries. Perhaps also explore `grep -F file` which lets you put the patterns in a file (maybe then also switch to using `grep -f`).

Comment: @tripleee, cat here is just for demonstration purposes. OP uses grep to parse output of `ifconfig`, and I prefer not to change their command to ease understanding. Same goes for `-f`.

Comment: @tripleee, regarding `-w`: it feels like it would be better as a separate answer.